# Add item to resource files (resx) programmatically - asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resx

I have three resource files (english, spanish and italian) in my project. Admin has the ability to add new items for selection list and i am currently storing Name and Value in database. Now on language change i want to implement creation of new items in all three resource files so instead of storing display strings for Name in database i would store resource name and application would display it according to language.

So when admin adds new item to selection list it would also be required to  enter translation for all three languages and application would create new keys in resource files.

My question is can this be done and how? I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Resources are compiled so in order to get it done you need to modify .resx file (which is basically xml) and then recompile the sources - But you obviously can not do it from the application itself

Comment: Yea i was afraid of that but kinda hoped there is a way :D I want to avoid having everything language vise in db. Thank you